# How to aggregate datasets for Policy Aggregation in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

I am trying to run policy aggregation for a particular problem and I am confused on how to aggregate the two policies in Python. In policy aggregation, you have some initial policy on a dataset, and as you train you collect expert (oracle) actions, train a separate policy on that, and then combine those two policies with a particular weight distribution to get a new policy to predict states for the next training iteration.

Currently, I am using VotingClassifier with a soft voting. The issue here is that, one it uses the predictions from the individual models and doesn't really create a new model. Second, this new model has to be fit again to some dataset. If I used the initial or the expert dataset, the model doesn't learn, if I train on the aggregated dataset, it does improve, but the approach resembles another method DAgger. I am not sure how the papers that use it actually implement it.

Is there any other approach I can try to merge these two policies, which are trained on different datasets but that have the same features and classes (same X and y)?